# How to set discount per product per customer group?

Tags: magento, discount, usergroups

I need to set a discount in percentage for product per customer group through the admin panel. I know there is Magento Promotion rules. But I want to set it as "per product per user group"  .

[image]

I need something like this.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is this a programming-related question?

Comment: ys.. i want to set it from adminpanel..

Comment: You want to code an extension for admin or you just want to know how to set the discount using admin?

Comment: I want to know the possible ways to do this..

Answer (score 0):

**Shopping Cart Price Rules**

The *Shopping Cart Price Rules* are the right way to do this.

You can configure the following rule.

1. Make the product SKU usable for the *Shopping Cart Price Rules* in *Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > sku > Use for Promo Rule Conditions*. Set this value to `Yes`.
   [image]
2. Reindex all indices under *System > Index Management*.
3. Add a new *Shopping Cart Price Rule* under *Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules* and choose the *Wholesale* customer group under *Rule Information > Customer Groups*.
   [image]
4. Contrain the rule for your specific product SKU under *Actions > 
   Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)*.
   [image]

**Edit the prices per customer group on a single product**

5. You can also edit the prices as fixed discount prices per customer group under *Catalog > Manage Products > Choose Product > Prices*. You can't set percentages for Simple Products and it depends on the configuration of the product types like Config, Bundle etc. if the discounts can be set as percentage values.
   That's the way to set a discount for a **single product** for a special customer group.
   [image]
6. If you want overall catalog rules for specific customer groups, which are also displayed in product lists (category lists) and product detail pages (product view), then create a *Catalog Price Rule* under *Promotions > Catalog Price Rule*.
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: Thanks Michael.. I tried this but my client want to set discount from product  information page.ie Product Information ->Prices

Comment: @dhi_m I've edited my answer. Are these ways possible for your client?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding **Tier Price** for each customer group. You can also add price for each group by clicking on **Add Group Price** button.

[image: Check Image]